# SQLite3 Unbuffered Query

Tags: php, sqlite, unbuffered-queries

I am converting some old code in PHP from SQLite2 to SQLite3.

One of the lines uses the following code:

```
$result = sqlite_unbuffered_query($this->db, $sqlite_query);
```

Is it possible to perform an unbuffered query in SQLite3? I can't seem to find anything on the SQL3 website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQLite C API, all queries are unbuffered.

Neither do the PHP SQLite3 functions implement buffering.

Comment: Tried it the same way I've been doing all my other queries and encountered no issues. Thanks for your help.